# push additional arrays to serialized form data to be sent via AJAX

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have a form that I am submitting using AJAX. In order to get the data from the form to the PHP script, I am serializing the data. In addition to that data I would like to include another array from dynamic data that is coming from outside the form. Here's an example of what I have:

```js
$(function() {
  var $form = $('form'),
      formData = $form.serializeArray(),
      arr = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; /* Just an example array */
  
  formData.push({name: 'dynamic-array', arr});
  
  console.log(formData);
  
  /*
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com',
    data: formData
  }).done(function() {
    console.log('Submitted');
  });
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="name" type="text" value="Lorem" />
  <input name="number" type="text" value="Ipsum" />
</form>
```

So when I console log `formData` after pushing the array to the serialized form data, it correctly shows that additional array. However, when I try to `print_r($_POST)` in my PHP form, the additional array is not accessible:

```
Array ( [name] => Lorem [number] => Ipsum [dynamic-array] => )
```

The `dynamic-array` doesn't have the array associated with it.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the serialized array returned from `serializeArray` is an array of objects with a property called `key`, which holds the key name, and a property called `value`, which holds the value. Your new object doesn't have a `value` key, so it's not getting processed correctly on the backend. Try `{name: 'dynamic-array', value: arr}` instead.

Comment: Ok, now the data is coming through in my `print_r($_POST)`, but it appears that the data has been converted from an array to a comma separated string. Is there any way to push the additional array to the serialized form data while maintaining the array structure? Within the PHP script I would like to be able to do a `foreach` on the `dynamic-array` key

Comment: Form encoding doesn't handle raw arrays like that; it will always treat them as a string. If you want to pass an array raw to the PHP backend, you have two options: (1) Don't use form encoding; instead, send the entire array of serialized data as a JSON string and use the `application/json` contentType in your ajax call. Then the server can decode the JSON object and have all the proper types back. Or (2) serialize the subarray itself into `{name, value}` objects like the rest of it, and use an array-format name for them (like `dynamicArray[]`) -- PHP will automatically parse that kind of name

Comment: So what would be the best way to send through the form data along with the additional array(s) in the AJAX call. Sorry, I'm not really following your latest comment.

Comment: As I said, you can set the `contentType` option in the AJAX call to `application/json` and then pass the data as a JSON string (that is, `JSON.stringify(formData)`), then on the backend you can use the PHP function `json_decode` to get the raw formData array back. Or you can stick with the form encoding and serialize the dynamic array with an array-syntax name; something like this instead of pushing the object: `formData.concat(arr.map(value => {name: 'dynamicArray[]', value: value }))` Then your PHP will get those values in an array called `$_POST['dynamicArray']`

Comment: Thank you, I tried the 2nd suggestion, but `formData.concat(arr.map(value => {name: 'dynamicArray[]', value: value })` is returning this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: Yup, that's what I get for writing code in a tiny comment off-hand :D Thanks to the syntax of object literals and code blocks both being delimited with curly brackets, the line I posted is ambiguous. Just needs some parentheses to disambiguate it. Try this version: `formData.concat(arr.map(value => ({name: 'dynamicArray[]', value: value })))`